# Convert decimal to binary with reflection and generics in the static Convert class?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, type-conversion

I'm trying to make a static generic function to convert decimal (*numeric type*) to a binary string.

Let me explain.
I know that what I have to do is this:

```
int number = 12;
string binaryString = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
```

This is simple, but I also want to make the convertion decimal to binary with other parameters types, like **bytes**, shorts(**Int16**), longs(**Int64**). I know that Convert.Tostring() have all of the overloads for that and I simple need to do overloads like:

```
public static string DecToBinary(short number)
{
   return Convert.ToString(number, 2);
}

public static string DecToBinary(long number)
{
   return Convert.ToString(number, 2);
}
//etc
```

But I want to make it with generics and reflection...
So I tried this:

```
public static string DecToBinary<T>(T number) where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
   return (string)typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ToString").Invoke(null, new object[] { number, 2 });
}
```

But I'm getting a problem on runtime that say:

> Ambiguous match found.

and make sense, since reflection use a **object** as parameter type and never know what type I want...

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Comment: I'd say just type out all the overloads, there aren't that many. Write a little script to generate all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the overloads of [Type.GetMethod()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Type___) which allow you to provide an array of parameter types (`Type[]`). This should help the CLR resolve the correct overload of the `Convert.ToString()` method.